# Windows phone Web service call using http request

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Some time before I faced an issue while making network request. When I call a same webservice multiple times.I get same set of data. It seems that the Network library caches the http requests-responses. Initially I added NO-CACHE in the header, but it did not work.Hence I added a timestamp field as a workaround which works. But I want to know if there is any better solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a timestamp to the end of the URL you are requesting? e.g. `http://somewhere.com/Request?2012-04-17-10-09-31` or `http://somewhere.com/Request?param=val&ts=2012-04-17-10-09-31`

Comment: Yes as I said this already works using a timestamp. But I want a better solution.